# How i can create a object(div) on document?

Tags: javascript

I would like create one div on body, any time i send a request post to my localhost. But he return all time "document is not defined", someone can help me?

```
app.post('/tshirt/:id', (req, res) => {
url.push(req.body.Musica);
User.push(req.body.User);

for (let index = 0; index < url.length; ++index) {
    let elemento = document.createElement("div");
    let padre = document.body("sendMusics");
    let referencia = document.getElementById("dsmuix")[index];
    elemento.innerHTML='<div id="dsmuix" style="background-color:blue; width:97%; height: 75px;margin-top: 1px;margin-left: 2%;width: 50%;height: 100%;float: left;" ><label style="margin-top:15px;display:inline-block;margin-left: 5%;">'+url[index]+'(time)<br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;'+User[index]+'</label></div>';
   padre.insertBefore(elemento, referencia); 
}});
```

Can help me? Thanks

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```js
const createElement = () =>{
const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = 'it works'
document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
}
document.body.onload = createElement
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey adriceniza, thanks for helping me. But i try your code many ways and dont work, on my program. But open on jsfiddle and work... 
[He dont work because this.](https://prnt.sc/WcxhFViVzQUM)